# Whats causing a very small leak after cleanUp in my AS3? Scout File Included

Tags: actionscript-3, firefox, video, adobe-scout

I have this FlashPro/AS3 project I'm working on, and thanks to the help of @vesper and others, I've managed to make significant headway.

At the moment though, there seems to be a slight leak in memory. A very small one at best. I've set up traces such as this one in a few places.

Trace:
`trace("On Load" + System.totalMemory / 1024);`

Locations:
`On Load` `doCleanUp` `launchVideo`

The leak is pretty small, and according to Scout, most likely related to something in the Uncategorized memory I think.

Here is the scout file - [Scout File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpv5mw2fm5x9mdd/MP-Interactive-3.1-Results.flm?dl=0)

Heres is the [Full code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngxubgfbc26azub/new-mp-code-v3.1.as?dl=0)

It would be awesome if I could get another pair of eyes on the output.

Test results show...
1) One video being clicked and left to play out
2) Two(2) videos played and stopped/dismissed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quick look at Scout Session and comparing early frames with last ones it looks like it's using a bit more memory indeed. However... in "Current Total Memory" panel you can see it's in "Other -> Network Buffers" (at the end you have like 8,966 KB in there). So my guess is netStream is not being cleaned properly. After 1st one (at about 1:12) it's only 182 KB, but after second one (1:25) it's 7,320 KB.

Also - is there a reason why in doCleanup() function you're not calling `vp.close();` ? According to [DOCUMENTATION](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/VideoPlayer.html#close%28%29) that should force stream to close.

Also 2 - Are you sure it's all garbage collected? You can try to call `System.gc();` after cleaning. It's working perfectly in AIR, not as good in flash player, but worth giving a try. You can also force garbage collector in Scout. If you go to "Memory Allocations" tab (bottom part if you're using default layout) and there should be little bin icon. See if it does make any difference.

Comment: I've been avoiding using System.gc(); as I've read in several places, that "technically" we don't have control over GC, and if we're in a situation where we need to force GC, we have a significant leak. Albeit, I'm unable to find what is causing this at this time. I've added `System.gc();` in two places, and it seems to have improved a bit. Now the leak is something like ~0.4kb.

Comment: is it better to set the forced GC to a timer or count rather than `onCleanup'

Comment: That's true with GC, but it was worth to check how much memory is allocated after that, because it's still being "used" before GC decide to free it.       And again "Also - is there a reason why in doCleanup() function you're not calling vp.close(); ?"

Comment: vp.close wasn't completely closing the nestreams. In the code I left a small note on that `// Used to be close();`

Comment: Yeah, I saw the comment but you didn't said why it's used to be. How do you know it is not completely closing the nestreams ?

Comment: I was running Adobe Scout, while using `vp.close();` and during our multi-tap test (rapid fire start and stop of playback simulating a child clicking repeatedly) Scout showed the number of `netstreams` growing with each click. Something like  `processing netstreams x2` `processing netstreams x3` `processing netstreams x4` and so on. I swapped it out for `dispose();` and they all closed.